# Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure

Tags: jenkins, maven, java, tomcat

I have Jenkins installed in my system, on which the following are installed:

- Maven Integration Plugin
- Deploy to Container Plugin
- Ant Plugin
- Copy Artifact Plugin
- GitHub plugin
- GitHub Branch Source Plugin

.. and possibly a few others I cannot remember (because coding)...

create new freestyle Project (Deploy-to-staging) project, go to its config, and do the following:

- In Build, select copy artifacts from another project (package):

[image: In Build, select copy artifacts from another project (package):]

- In select post build action

  [image: In select post build action]

In package project, edited its config as follows:

- In General, describe the project.
- In Source Code Management, select Git and enter the Repository URL.
- In Build,Select Invoke top-level Maven Target.

[image: In Build, Invoke top-level Maven Target.]

- In post build actions, Select Archive the Artifacts and Build other project.

[image: In post build actions, Select Archive the Artifacts and Build other project.]

When I trigger the package build it runs fine and Deploy-to-staging

Build step failed with exception org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy

I get below error when trying to deploy a WAR using Jenkins.

```
    Building in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Deploy-to-staging
Copied 1 artifact from "Package" build number 31
Deploying /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Deploy-to-staging/webapp/target/webapp.war to container Tomcat 7.x Remote with context 
ERROR: Build step failed with exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to redeploy [/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Deploy-to-staging/webapp/target/webapp.war]
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:188)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1077)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1060)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1844)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The username and password you provided are not correct (error 401)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:698)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:876)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:889)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:173)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8090/manager/text/list
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:571)
    ... 20 more
org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The username and password you provided are not correct (error 401)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:698)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.list(TomcatManager.java:876)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.getStatus(TomcatManager.java:889)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.redeploy(AbstractTomcatManagerDeployer.java:173)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:77)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:147)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$DeployCallable.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:117)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1077)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:1060)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:114)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.redeploy(PasswordProtectedAdapterCargo.java:93)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:64)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.post2(Build.java:186)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1844)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://localhost:8090/manager/text/list
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1894)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:571)
    ... 20 more
Build step 'Deploy war/ear to a container' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I fix this?

My tomcat credentials, located in [tomcat directory]/conf/tomcat-users.xml, are as follows:

```
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-script,admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>
```

Comment: How did u fix this issue? I am facing the same exact problem. And my credentials to tomcat container look good.

Answer (score 1):

Quickly going through this it looks like you have added wrong credentials to Jenkins. Can you please check the added credentials first.

```
aused by: org.codehaus.cargo.container.tomcat.internal.TomcatManagerException: The username and password you provided are not correct (error 401)
```